# React Native Text adjustsFontSizeToFit Not Working Properly on Android Without Interaction

Tags: android, react-native

I am working on a React Native application and have encountered a problem with the 'Text' component on Android. I am using the 'Text' component with the adjustsFontSizeToFit, numberOfLines={1}, and minimumFontScale={0.5} properties.

In my app, there are several 'Text' components nested within a 'View' with 'flexDirection: row'. The issue I am facing is that the text size doesn't adjust correctly when the app is first started on Android. The text is initially too large and only displays correctly after there has been an interaction that causes a new render of the component.

This issue only occurs on Android - on iOS, everything works as expected.

Here is my code:

```
<View style={styles.subInfo}>
              <Ionicons
                style={styles.icon}
                name='list'
                size={18}
                color={COLORS.buttonGrey}
              />
              <Text
                style={[
                  styles.subInfoText,
                  { fontSize: responsiveFontSize(1.4) },
                ]}
                adjustsFontSizeToFit
                numberOfLines={1}
                minimumFontScale={0.5}
              >
                {category}
              </Text>
            </View>
```

styles:

```
subInfo: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  subInfoText: {
    fontFamily: 'poppins',
    flex: 1,
  },
```